# How to determine correct apk from list of apks of android app bundle

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-app-bundle

[image]

When I unzip my .aab file I get the below list of apks.
How do I determine which apk is actually being used for a given device.
I understand difference between arm and x86. How about narrowing down other values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you know about arm and x86. the rest of the name (xdpi,hdpi,xhdpi) denotes the **SCREEN PIXEL DENSITIES** of the device you are using.

What should you do now?

Take your device model number and you can find out the device category [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support)

or simply you can go [Here](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/android-basics-find-your-phones-screen-density-value-320-dpi-480-dpi-640-dpi-etc-0176363/) to find out your apk

To develop layouts that fits for all categories refer the  (official documentation) https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Hope it helps!

Comment: how to know if it is v7a or v8a etc ?

Comment: @jayshah armeabi-v7a is the modern arch which supports floating point operations, multi- threading safe is used on multi-cpu devices. It is also 32-bit.

arm64-v8a is 64-bit arch,  i can say 99% of the device do not run armeabi.             And now 64-bit arch is mandatory from Aug 1,2019 to publish app in play store refer [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)

Comment: I have a device, is there a quick way to get the details? some adb command?

Comment: @jayshah Run 'adb shell getprop ro.sf.lcd_density' you will get the screen density of your device.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean when you unzipped the `.apks` and not the `.aab`.

You can use [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#device_specific_apks) to extract and/or install the APKs for a specific device. The public documentation is quite detailed so would recommend going through it.

For completion of this answer, here are the commands you can use:

```
bundletool extract-apks
    --apks=/MyApp/my_existing_APK_set.apks
    --output-dir=/MyApp/my_pixel2_APK_set.apks
    --device-spec=/MyApp/bundletool/pixel2.json
```

(You can generate the `.json` file using the `get-device-spec` command)

or

```
bundletool install-apks --apks=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

to directly install the APKs on the connected device.

Hope that helps.